# How do I test for a username and password in an HTTP request?

Tags: python, python-requests, httprequest, pytest, basic-authentication

I'm making an HTTP GET request (with the [requests library](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/)) that includes basic authentication:

```py
requests.get("https://httpbin.org/get", auth=("fake_username", "fake_password"))
```

How do I test for the existence of the correct username and password in the request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mock the request (with [requests-mock](https://requests-mock.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html)), Base64 encode the username and password, and assert (with [pytest](https://pytest.org/en/latest/)) on the `last_request.headers["Authorization"]` key. For example:

```py
def test_make_request():
    with requests_mock.Mocker() as mock_request:
        mock_request.get(requests_mock.ANY, text="success!")
        requests.get("https://httpbin.org/get", auth=("fake_username", "fake_password"))

    encoded_auth = b64encode(b"fake_username:fake_password").decode("ascii")

    assert mock_request.last_request.headers["Authorization"] == f"Basic {encoded_auth}"
```